# Apart from '귀차니즘', are there any other kinds of 'isms' in Korean?

Tags: colloquial-language, konglish

I recently learned the word '귀차니즘' - laziness - , from '귀찮다' and the English suffix '-ism'. It seems like adding '-ism' should be quite productive but I couldn't think of any other 'Konglish' words made like this.

Are there any other kinds of '-ism' in Korean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I've heard [먹고사니즘](http://www.sisain.co.kr/?mod=news&act=articleView&idxno=16378) which means (something like) the idea that making a living (and feeding yourself) is the most important thing and other stuff can wait.

There may be others, but fixing a Korean word with "-ism" feels quite slang-ish, so you might not find many such forms in any "respectable" publication.

Answer (score 2):

A [search](http://m.endic.naver.com/search.nhn?searchOption=all&query=%EB%8B%88%EC%A6%98&=) in Naver Dictionary shows:

- 커넥션니즘: connectionism
- 이마지니즘: Imazhinizm
- 헬리콘니즘: Heliconism

None of those are even common words in English, so it seems to have pretty limited productivity.

A far more productive suffix would be the Sino-Korean version of "-ism" [주의](http://m.endic.naver.com/krenEntry.nhn?entryId=63cf7c92eadf4267b5503aa8a7263c25) making words such as:

- 제국주의: imperialism
- 자유주의: liberalism
- 공산주의: communism
- 민주주의: democracy (not an -ism in English, but you get the idea)

Comment: I didn't even think to search for '니즘'. I tried [이즘](http://m.endic.naver.com/krenEntry.nhn?entryId=0e752fe0499c489c9eab91878eca3aa7) too but it seems to be more focused on the anglicised versions. Good point about 주의 !

Answer (score 2):

The word 귀차니즘 has been around for about a decade now, I think, and it's been quite popular among younger generations. I've heard 먹고사니즘 too lately, as jick mentioned, and there should be other words like that which have succeeded in gaining a small amount of popularity. However I don't think there are any similar "Konglish" words that are popular as much as 귀차니즘.

Comment: Thanks, really useful to know about the frequency of usage.